# Swift 4: Access Variables from DispatchQueue.main (Scope)

Tags: swift, scope, dispatch-queue

I have a CoreML Image Classification task, that takes the "live stream" from the iOS device's [video] camera and occurs in the background. Once objects have been been identified, and other app logic has occurred, I would like to update the UI's label with some of the data.

Can someone explain how the callout to `DispatchQueue.main.asyc(execute: { })` is able to access the variable(s) I have been working with? I think this is essentially a scoping issue?

The code I am currently using:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    processCameraBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)

}

func processCameraBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {

    let coreMLModel = Inceptionv3()

    if let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: coreMLModel.model) {
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: { (request, error) in
            if let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] {

                var counter = 0
                var otherVar = 0

                for item in results[0...9] {

                    if item.identifier.contains("something") {
                        print("some app logic goes on here")
                        otherVar += 10 - counter
                    }
                    counter += 1

                }
                switch otherVar {
                case _ where otherVar >= 10:
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let displayVarFormatted = String(format: "%.2f", otherVar / 65 * 100)
                        self.labelPrediction.text = "\(counter): \(displayVarFormatted)%"
                    })
                default:
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.labelPrediction.text = "No result!"
                    })
                }
            }
        })

            if let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
                let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:])
                do {
                    try handler.perform([request])
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Its the `self.labelPrediction.text = ""` lines inside the switch statement that is causing the issue. This var is always 0 currently.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the line you mentioned and see what the variables contain.  (Generally, blocks capture the values they need.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the matter of `DispatchQueue`. From `processCameraBuffer(sampleBuffer:)`, your code update your UI before it get result.

To solve this, you need to use `escaping closure`. Your function should look like this.

```
func processCameraBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, completion: @escaping (Int, String) -> Void) {
    // 2.
    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: { (request, error) in

      DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
          // 3.
          let displayVarFormatted = String(format: "%.2f", otherVar / 65 * 100)
          completion(counter, displayVarFormatted)
      })
    }
}

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) { 
    // 1.
    processCameraBuffer(sampleBuffer) { counter, displayVarFormatted in
        /*
         This Closure will be executed from 
         completion(counter, displayVarFormatted)
        */
        // 4.
        self.labelPrediction.text = "\(counter): \(displayVarFormatted)%"
    }
}
```

Scope of variable is not a problem from here. You need to handle asynchronous task.

1. Capture occurs.
2. processCameraBuffer is called and `VNCoreMLRequest` executed.
3. You will get data and execute `processCameraBuffer`'s completion block, by `completion()`.
4. Update Label.

Comment: Thanks @changnam-hong. This function is called from a "live stream" from the iOS device's camera:

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        
        processCameraBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)
        
    }

So this is executed on every frame capture. And it needs to continually rescan the video stream so image classification continually happens.

Does this change the answer?

Comment: I have implemented my code to follow this format. However, at step 4 XCode is still complaining that the `self.labelPrediction.text = ""` line still needs to be run on the main thread.

When I change this back to a `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`, once again this variable is never set (or is set to 0).